# WordPress Language Page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I've installed WordPress and played with it for a while. And I got a question how I can make a top page which let visitors to choose their languages.

Let's say there ware two languages for a website, English and Japanese. When a visitor opens the domain root(http://example.com), a selection page appears. If English is clicked, it redirects to the page "http://example.com/en", which has been created by WordPress's page feature(permalink). If it is Japanese, it goes to example(dot)com/jp."

Comment: Why would you do that? This is terrible for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of page is annoying and most of the time useless. As you can automatically detect user browser language and/or ip location, or display a language switcher anywhere in your website.

If you need it anyway, you can try WPML plugin (or other free alternative, if you find one...).
Then you can easily test if you have a detected language and if there is not, display your language chooser.

Comment: Its for a job I have and have no say in the matter. Thats how they wanted done can you please explain to me how I would do this.